# JS single-page application and PHP based logging in system?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, reactjs, relay

Im currently working on a single-page application and Im using React and Relay to achieve this.

I have several components which are very different or even absent if user is not logged in (*e.g* logged in user dropdown menu, profile page, access to member content *etc*).

Important thing to note is that Im using WordPress as `CMS`. Logging in is currently done *via* normal `HTTP` and with normal page refresh. WordPress sets few sessions to logged in users.

---

The problem.. I have a very easy WordPress way (**one-liner**) to check in `PHP` if user is logged in.

- I have no idea why  but `AJAX` (even with like 20 bytes of data) has very often huge loading times (few seconds). I would need to check if user is logged in very often and this is unacceptable. My connection and server is fine, "normal" pages takes almost the same time to load. That means that sending `AJAX` request, checking if user is logged in in server *via* `PHP` is not an option.
- I cannot *capture* the session keys or values because these are both randomly generated, not stored in database in any way and it would probably be a huge safety concern. That means that I cannot check, if my "secret" variable value in `JS` equals session key or value.

---

**Can I and (if yes) how could I match these 2 technologies?** I can't see a way to drop the WordPress logging in system because the whole `CMS` depends on that and it would be very painful to change that.. **Or should I use *separate* JS logging in mechanism in front-end?** Users don't have access to WordPress back-end, only admins do.

Even if you don't have a good solid answer, all suggestions are very welcomed in comments!

Comment: Not 100% sure I'm following, but does `localStorage` sound like a solution?

Comment: @sg.cc Im not sure I understand the question.. What exactly could I store there safely without any security concerns? I need to check if user is logged in almost every time `URL` (route) changes and it has to be **fast** or single-page application (no page refreshes, everything is very responsive and fast) would lose it's purpose..

Comment: Well, generally speaking, `localStorage` is intended to be more secure than sessions or cookies. However, if that's not enough, consider using Javascript Web Tokens, JWT (one of the many advantages of which is that it is in fact fast). This could be added to your application to work alongside the PHP session solution from WP and stored in `localStorage`.

Comment: May I ask, why you need to check if the user is logged in every time the URL changes instead of doing it once ? If someone decides to mess with your application, then maybe he'll see some components he shouldn't, but the data won't be there anyway...

Comment: @KubaBirecki Could you specify how to overcome the security problem in your opinion? Let's say that I will check if user is logged in if he/she actually logs in and I set a variable? Users have several levels: _e.g_ "normal" and "VIP", I set this as variable too? Now, when user clicks on a link, I would use conditional logic based on user level what content to show him/her.. How do I know that user didn't alter the `JS` and set his/her level higher than it actually is before clicking on a link? It would serve him different content, wouldn't it? I can't wrap my head around the `JS` security..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no need to check if the user is logged in on every part of a single page application. Let me explain how I do it:

Login/logout happens via a simple call to the relative endpoint. I use a separate endpoint to return users data, which results in a `404` if a user is not logged in. That's just my way of doing things, you could just as well return that data from the login endpoint, if the login was successful.

Now, even though it's a single page application, and we use ajax for communication between the app and the server, server sessions still continue to exist. This means that the logic for checking whether a user is logged in remains the same for both non-ajax and ajax calls. Based on that you can secure your backend to only return the data that's accessible by a user.

Going back to the single page application. You log in once, and you store the necessary information like user level etc. in your application. Now it's true, that this data can be easily compromised. But you shouldn't worry about that too much, since it only affects the current user, and the backend won't actually permit him to do anything he's not allowed to do anyway.

So for example, a person changes his user level from 'normal' to 'admin'. Now he can view some parts of the application he wouldn't be able to view normally. But, he will see no content, as the backend will refuse to send him that data anyway. He might see some options that weren't available to him before, but again, even though he might send these requests, the backend will not process them.

Let me know in case I misunderstood what you're trying to do, or you still need some clarification.

Comment: May I ask you, what database endpoints have you used? GraphQL or REST? As far as I know, WordPress REST API endpoints are "automatically" secure thanks to the work of the authors while GraphQL (which I would need to use thanks to Relay.js) requires a lot of research and development from scratch because it's pretty much the new kind in town - not much to read in the web.. I've actually thought about using a paid third party security service because Im pretty new to SPA-s and full JS solutions..

Comment: I used a custom REST API built specifically for that project. I'm pretty sure it's very similar to WordPress REST API in terms of how it works. Generally, you have to assume the user can send anything to your backend, therefor you always have to validate the users identity. And therefor, it's simply impossible to only have client side security.